# What does this step mean in this limits problem??

Tags: analysis, limits

> Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(-3+\cos(n\pi/2)) = -\infty.$

Well $(-3+\cos(n\pi/2)) \leq -2, \forall n \in \mathbb N.$ Therefore $n$ multiplied by that is always less than $-2n$, which has a limit of $-\infty.$ At this point I would say therefore $n(-3+\cos(n\pi/2))$ also has a limit of $-\infty$ but instead the answers say:

So given $L$ belonging to the real numbers, if $n \geq  -0.5L$, then:

$n(-3+\cos(n\pi/2)) \leq -2n \leq L$

Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(-3+ \cos(n\pi/2)) = -\infty.$

What does this step with "$L$" mean and why is it neccessary? Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @Wolverine: I've edited your question. See if it's fine.

Comment: @Krish Thanks, it looks fine.

Comment: @amWhy I know that already, it = 0 for all odd n. I don't see what the L step is saying though or why it's needed.

Comment: I think you want to say that $-3 + \cos(n\pi/2) \leq -2$. (Your claim following "Well..."), then the second sentence follows. (You currently have $2$ instead of $-2$.

Comment: @amwhy Thanks, yes I meant -2, it got changed with krish's edit. Anyway, can you help with my question at all?

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)=-\infty$ is an abbreviation ( or euphemism) for $\forall L\in R\;\exists M_L\;(n\geq M_L\implies f(n)<L).$..... The value of $M_L$ usually depends on $L. $  The answer you were given is showing that this holds when  $M_L=-L/2.$

But your reasoning is sound.It is not always required to spell out all the details, unless either you are instructing someone who is unfamiliar with it, or you have to show someone that you understand the details.